# "error-handeling" tag should be "error handling"

Tags: bug, status-completed

Just a spelling mistake that should be corrected and I am not able to.

The "error-handeling" tag should be "error handling."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were only 4 questions with bad tag, I fixed them. Old tag should be destroyed automatically soon.

Just by the way, I doubt if this tag is useful.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could just edit the questions.

Comment: @PatrickKenny only feasible if there is not a lot of them. If there are many, more dire solutions are needed